# Why are deleted rows reappearing in an excel table when the filter in removed in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code I have has worked perfectly on two other machines and with several other worksheets without the data reappearing. I've created a macro that takes a master spreadsheet and creates a new spreadsheet for each school listed in the table. I just got a new laptop and installed Excel 365 on it. I copied the VBA code to the new machine, but when I ran it, each new worksheet still contained the data for all the schools, not just the school for that particular file. I stepped through the code, and the schools did delete, but when it got to the part where the filter was removed from the table `ws.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData`, all the deleted rows reappeared. I'm stumped on why this is happening - It didn't happen on the other two machines and other iterations of the file that I've used this macro on. I don't know if it's an Excel setting or a setting on this particular master file. The other two machines - one used Excel 365, and the other Excel 2016.  The data is not part of PowerPivot  and is not a PowerQuery, so the data only lives in the table in the worksheet.

Here is the macro:

```
Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, schools() As Variant, schools_to_delete() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, dt As String
schools = SchoolsInList()
dt = MonthName(Month(Now)) & " " & Year(Now)

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 1 To UBound(schools)
    wb.SaveCopyAs ("Galileo " & dt & " " & schools(i) & ".xlsx")
    Workbooks.Open ("Galileo " & dt & " " & schools(i) & ".xlsx")
    Workbooks("Galileo " & dt & " " & schools(i) & ".xlsx").Activate
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    ws.Activate
    schools_to_delete = schools
    schools_to_delete(i) = "x"
    Set rng = ws.ListObjects("Data").DataBodyRange

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        ws.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
        Array(schools_to_delete), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        ws.Range(rng.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        ws.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call SelectA1
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Function SchoolsInList() As Variant
Dim schools() As String
Dim C As Collection
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim last_row As Long
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set C = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Each r In Worksheets("Data").Range("R2:R" & last_row).Cells
    C.Add r.Value, CStr(r.Value)
Next

On Error GoTo 0

ReDim A(1 To C.Count)

For i = 1 To C.Count
    A(i) = C.Item(i)
Next i

SchoolsInList = A

End Function


Sub SelectA1()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Sheets(i).Activate
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Range("A1").Select
Next i
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you enable screen updating and step through the code with `F8` to see what's happening.

Comment: I would also avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`...May help to clarify things.

Comment: I did step through the code with F8 initially - I did it again to re-check and found that the rows aren't actually deleted, but are being hidden.  Initially, when I clicked "Show All" I only saw one school - this time I saw that the rows weren't contiguous, and used clear filters instead, and found that the data had just been hidden.

Comment: try `.entirerow.delete` if you're trying to remove the whole row that is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - the .AutoFilterMode = False didn't actually clear the filters that had already been placed on the table in question.  The visible data WAS deleted, but the data that was filtered before the macro was run remained, and when the  ws.ListObjects("Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData ran, it cleared the previous filter, showing the rows that had been filtered before.  I added the .ShowAllData code to the beginning of the With statement to avoid the same problem at a future date.